# I installed MySQL, but I can't access it via terminal

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, terminal

I installed MySQL, it seems to be running and working properly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLBGc.png

But I go to Terminal and no MySQL commands are recognized.

Comment: Have you checked your PATH, is the directory you intalled the mysql client in in your list of directories?

Comment: That was the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the MySQL Client tools.

There are command line versions of these tools as well as GUI based tools you can use.